# an app supporting arm64 and armv7 running on arm64 and ios 7 ipad air

Tags: ipad, ios7, armv7, arm64

I have an app that is builded with armv7 and arm64 architecture. This app performed differently on iPad2(iOS 8) and iPadAir(iOS 7). On iPadAir, there are some variable are overflow. On iPad2, it's working totally fine. I have no idea that which architecture is running on iPadAir(iOS 7). Furthermore, how can I get the architecture of an app programmatically?

Comment: Check datatypes. I suppose you have integer or something like that (about overflow), so maybe you have old 32 data types when you change to 64 bits arquitecture have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can check programmatically doing a `Sizeof( CGFLOAT )`
it's `4` for `armv7` and `8` for `arm64`